# iOS tableview cell is empty at random

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[Screenshot of weird behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmK59.jpg)

The screenshot tells is quite well. I have a tableview with dynamic custom cells. I added a println for one of the contents of the cell to check, if the labels are set. I can see in the debug log, that each cell has its content. Still, on the device there are empty cells at random, which means, the row, where no content appears, is changing a lot. Even just scrolling up and down makes the second row disappear, but the third row is filled. Scrolling again turns this around again. If I close the app and start it again, every row is filled correctly.

Here is the code for the cell generation:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Return a count picker cell
    if countPickerTableRow == indexPath.row {

        ...
    }

    // Return a normal wish list entry cell
    else {

        let article = wishListEntries[indexPath.row]!
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ArticleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WOSArticleCell

        // Correct the order in case a count picker cell was inserted
        var row = indexPath.row
        if countPickerTableRow != -1 && indexPath.row > countPickerTableRow {
            row--
        }

        cell.setThePreviewImage(UIImage(data: article.thumbnail))

        cell.setArticleName(article.name)
        cell.setArticleDescription(article.text)
        cell.setArticleNumber(article.number)
        cell.setArticleCount(article.count as Int)
        cell.setOrderInTable(row)
        cell.setTableViewController(self)

        cell.setNeedsDisplay()

        cell.setInputAccessoryView(numberToolbar) // do it for every relevant textfield if there are more than one

        println(String(indexPath.row) + " " + cell.nameLabel.text!)

        return cell
    }
}
```

In the custom cell class there is nothing special. Just a few outlets to the labels.

Here is a screen of the storyboard:
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VoKm.png)

Can anyone please help me finding out what is going on here? I can't find the reason why the debug log can output the contents of a cell, but the device is not able to render them.

Comment: What happens if you comment out 'var row = indexPath.row
        if countPickerTableRow != -1 && indexPath.row > countPickerTableRow {
            row--
        }' ? Not sure what your countPickerTableRow is there for, but when using 'row--', you're probably deleting the row after it's been allocated, which could result in the cell showing no data.

Comment: row is just an Int. There is two types of cells in this table view. If the user selects a field in the ArticleCell, it opens an picker right under the cell. In this PickerCell the user can adjust the count of the article above. I keep track of which cell leads to which entry in my data source by setting this row value. But decrementing an Int value should not break the whole table rendering. I testet it, though. It does not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the logic of your code. If the PickerCell comes up just call reloadData() and reload everything in the tableview. If the amount of rows you have is small this won’t be an issue and it’s not an expensive operation as you are not doing any heavy calculating during display.

If you need to update only a single cell because of changes you made in the PickerCell then you should be calling  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: with the indexPath of the cell to be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But do you think the empty cells have something to do with the PickerCell? The other cells already appear empty just after changing to the tab with the table view. No interaction involved, that has anything to do with PickerCells. countPickerTableRow is always -1, so the PickerCell related code is skipped.

Comment: I can't tell from your code as you just display what's in one method so I don't have context. I'm also not sure why you are calling cell.setNeedsDisplay() while you are already in the process of displaying the cell.

Comment: cell.setNeedsDisplay() was a desperate try to make the cells not be empty. I deleted the PickerCell from storyboard, commented out the related code,  reconnected the datasource, renamed the ArticleCell identifier, cleaned the project again and still there are empty cells showing up. Can I provide you more code? Which one would be of interest?

Comment: More code would be useful. There isn't enough info above. You can edit your question with updated code, preferably all the code that deal with the table view data and remove anything extra (show the class declaration). If wanted to strip down the project to the table view code and provide a link to download that would also help.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with your subclass WOSArticleCell. Have you implemented prepareForUse()? If you have, are you setting any properties to nil?

[UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/)

> **Discussion**
>
> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse
>   identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned
>   from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For
>   performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that
>   are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection
>   state. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
>   should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell
>   object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is
>   not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke
>   the superclass implementation.